# TestNg classpath setup in Maven project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am getting this error while running Testng Project

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG**

Below is the POM.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>WeWalkThru</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>      
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: please code and code location ? Why main class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From testng  version 6.9.9 the class `RemoteTestNG` is gone. You have to upgrade/downgrade eclipse testng plugin to solve issue. It’s version compatibility issue of testng maven dependency and testng eclipse plugin.